# C++ string.length() not usable in a constant expression

Tags: c++

Using c++. I have the following piece of code where I am trying to use template to pass the 
size of a 2d array to the function foo. However the issue is that the size passed to the template has to be constant. Any pointers are helpful, thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <size_t r, size_t c>
bool foo(bool (&arr)[r][c])
{
    cout << "foo\n";
}

int main() {
    string s = "abcd";
    const size_t N = s.length(); //is this incorrect?
    bool arr[N][N];
    foo<N, N>(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

It seems that string.length() or string.size() cannot be used to initialize a constant. When I try to compile I get the error:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:14:6: error: the value of ‘N’ is not usable in a constant expression
  foo<N, N>(arr);
      ^
main.cpp:12:15: note: ‘N’ was not initialized with a constant expression
  const size_t N = s.length();
               ^
main.cpp:14:9: error: the value of ‘N’ is not usable in a constant expression
  foo<N, N>(arr);
         ^
main.cpp:12:15: note: ‘N’ was not initialized with a constant expression
  const size_t N = s.length();
               ^
main.cpp:14:15: error: no matching function for call to ‘foo<N, N>(bool [N][N])’
  foo<N, N>(arr);
               ^
main.cpp:5:6: note: candidate: template<long unsigned int r, long unsigned int c> bool foo(bool (&)[r][c])
 bool foo(bool (&arr)[r][c])
      ^~~
main.cpp:5:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:14:15: error: the value of ‘N’ is not usable in a constant expression
  foo<N, N>(arr);
               ^
main.cpp:12:15: note: ‘N’ was not initialized with a constant expression
  const size_t N = s.length();
               ^
main.cpp:14:15: note: in template argument for type ‘long unsigned int’ 
  foo<N, N>(arr);
               ^
main.cpp:14:15: error: the value of ‘N’ is not usable in a constant expression
main.cpp:12:15: note: ‘N’ was not initialized with a constant expression
  const size_t N = s.length();
               ^
main.cpp:14:15: note: in template argument for type ‘long unsigned int’ 
  foo<N, N>(arr);
           ^
```

Comment: There is a huge difference between a `const`and a compile-time `constexpr`. The size of an array must be a **compile time** constant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ```
> const size_t N = s.length(); //is this incorrect?
> ```

it is well-formed and has well-defined behaviour.

> It seems that string.length() or string.size() cannot be used to initialize a constant.

Sure it can be. It can be used to initialise a run-time constant variable, which is what your `N` is.

But it cannot be used to initialise a **compile-time** constant. You're using your run-time constant variable in contexts that require a compile time constant expression.

A simple fix: Use the size of the string literal instead:

```
// could use constexpr too
const unsigned long N = std::size("abcd") - 1;
```

Note the `-1` to account for the null terminator.

Answer (score 4):

The term "constant expression" can be a bit confusing. It actually means something that is known at compile time. It's not the same as `const`.

You might want to check out the string_view class instead. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view

It is a non owning view of text that can refer to a `string`, a string literal and a couple other things.

In your case, since you are using string literals, you can use a `string_view` as a drop in replacement for `string`.

Answer (score 2):

This cannot work.

Although your string was initialised from a literal in this particular case, `std::string` has "dynamic" length so `std::string::length()` will never be a constant expression. It can never be used as a template argument because that value is not (again, in general) known at compile time when the template is instantiated.

And remember that `const` doesn't automatically make something a constant expression; despite its name, it doesn't really create a "constant" in that sense, merely a name for a variable, through which you cannot mutate that variable (after initialisation).

These days we can mark "real" constants with `constexpr`, and you'll get better diagnostics when you try to use that with a thing that doesn't fit the bill... such as the result of `std::string::length()`.

(However some constant expressions can be created without `constexpr`; for example, literals are constant expressions, as are the names of some `static const` things.)

You'll have to fall back on a vector of bools (but be careful! these are weird…) or replace your string with something else (like a character array, which FYI your literal already is…).

> Any pointers are helpful

For the same reason, pointers won't help here either. ;)

Comment: So weird, in fact, that `vector<bool>` gets [its own documentation page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool)!

Comment: @user4581301 It also gets a ton of `if constexpr` in my code :(